# MySQL distinct not working as intended

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a problem. I have filtering of products with checkbox clicks. But, when I click two different recording, It looks the same product again. I want it to look only clicked product.

Thanks.

```
$bcheck=trim(strip_tags($_POST['bcheck']));

$dizi = explode(',',$bcheck);
foreach ($dizi as $diziyaz){    

$filtrele=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM urunler 
           INNER JOIN urunozellikler ON urunler.id = urunozellikler.urunid 
            WHERE urunozellikler.id='$diziyaz' AND urunler.dil='tr' 
            AND urunler.onay='1'");

while($filtreleyaz=mysql_fetch_array($filtrele)){

echo $filtreleyaz["urunad"];

}

}
```

Comment: Your Distinct isn't doing anything, you  have `<distinct>` and then `*` meaning `Everything` so you're selecting Everything as well as Distinct Values

Comment: Read the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html)

Comment: Use a group by clause. BUT Only MySQL to my knowledge allows a lax syntax for group by. Most SQL implementations insist that you MUST specify all the non-aggregating columns. You should follow this practice even in MSQL because there is an option to turn on this sytax rule

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with iterating over bcheck value. It query database couple times so it will display product as many times as $bcheck size. What if you make something like this:

```
$bcheck=trim(strip_tags($_POST['bcheck']));

$dizi = explode(',',$bcheck);

$where = '';
foreach ($dizi as $diziyaz){    
     $where .= " OR urunozellikler.id='$diziyaz'";
}
$where = substr($where, 3);

$filtrele=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM urunler 
           INNER JOIN urunozellikler ON urunler.id = urunozellikler.urunid 
            WHERE ($where) AND urunler.dil='tr' 
            AND urunler.onay='1'");

while($filtreleyaz=mysql_fetch_array($filtrele)){

echo $filtreleyaz["urunad"];

}
```

This should fix your problem, but you should work on this code.

Comment: thank you. but, this code not working. Because, When I try, 
All products listed. Did not filtering.

Comment: Yes, I made mistake in logic. It's fixed, try now.

Answer (score 0):

change your query and specify your distinct column EX:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT  FROM urunler 
           INNER JOIN urunozellikler ON urunler.id = urunozellikler.urunid 
            WHERE urunozellikler.id='$diziyaz' AND urunler.dil='tr' 
            AND urunler.onay='1'
```

Comment: sorry, I use column name. But not working. when I click two different recording, It looks the same product again.

Comment: then their is no issue with your sql